# Adaptive Depth Bias for Shadow Maps Ray Casting

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, raytracing

I have found [this paper](http://jcgt.org/published/0003/04/08/paper-lowres.pdf) dealing with how to compute the perfect bias when dealing with shadow map.

**The idea is to:**

- get the texel used when sampling the shadowMap
- project the texel location back to eyeSpace (ray tracing)
- get the difference between your frament.z and the intersection with
  the fragment's face.

This way you have calculated the error which serve as the appropriate bias for z-fighting.

Now I am trying to implement it, but I experiment some troubles:
I am using a OrthoProjectionMatrix, so i think I don't need to divide by w back and forth.

I am good until I am computing the ray intersection with the face.
I have a lot of faces failing the test, and my bias is way to important.

This is my fragment shader code:

```
 float getBias(float depthFromTexture)
{
    vec3 n = lightFragNormal.xyz;
    //no need to divide by w, we got an ortho projection
    //we are in NDC [-1,1] we go to [0,1]
    //vec4 smTexCoord = 0.5 * shadowCoord + vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0);
    vec4 smTexCoord = shadowCoord;
    //we are in [0,1] we go to texture_space [0,1]->[0,shadowMap.dimension]:[0,1024]
    //get the nearest index in the shadow map, the texel corresponding to our fragment we use floor (125.6,237.9) -> (125,237)
    vec2 delta      = vec2(xPixelOffset, yPixelOffset);
    vec2 textureDim = vec2(1/xPixelOffset, 1/yPixelOffset);
    vec2 index      = floor(smTexCoord.xy * textureDim);

    //we get the center of the current texel, we had 0.5 to put us in the middle (125,237) -> (125.5,237.5)
    //we go back to [0,1024] -> [0,1],    (125.5,237.5) -> (0.12, 0.23)
    vec2 nlsGridCenter = delta*(index + vec2(0.5f, 0.5f));

    // go back to NDC [0,1] -> [-1,1]
    vec2 lsGridCenter = 2.0 * nlsGridCenter - vec2(1.0);

    //compute lightSpace grid direction, multiply by the inverse projection matrice or
    vec4 lsGridCenter4 = inverse(lightProjectionMatrix) * vec4(lsGridCenter, -frustrumNear, 0);
    vec3 lsGridLineDir = vec3(normalize(lsGridCenter4));

    /** Plane ray intersection **/
    // Locate the potential occluder for the shading fragment
    //compute the distance t we need to continue in the gridDir direction, the point is "t" far
    float ls_t_hit = dot(n, lightFragmentCoord.xyz) / dot(n, lsGridLineDir);
    if(ls_t_hit<=0){
        return 0; // i got a lot of negativ values it shouldn t be the case
    }
    //compute the point p with the face
    vec3  ls_hit_p = ls_t_hit * lsGridLineDir;


    float intersectionDepth = lightProjectionMatrix * vec4(ls_hit_p, 1.0f).z / 2 + 0.5;
    float fragmentDepth     = lightProjectionMatrix * lightFragmentCoord.z / 2 + 0.5;
    float result = abs(intersectionDepth - fragmentDepth);

    return result;
}
```

I am struggling with this line:

```
vec4 lsGridCenter4 = inverse(lightProjectionMatrix) * vec4(lsGridCenter, -frustrumNear, 0);
```

i don't know if i am correct maybe:

```
vec4(lsGridCenter, -frustrumNear, 1);
```

and of course the plane intersection

from wikipedia:

[image]
where:

- l  = my vector normalized direction
- Po = a point belonging to the the plane
- l0 = offset of the vector, I think it's the origin so in eye space it should be (0,0,0) i might be wrong here
- n = normal of the plane, the normal of my fragment in eyespace

in my code:

```
float ls_t_hit = dot(n, lightFragmentCoord.xyz) / dot(n, lsGridLineDir);
```

Comment: Thanks you for your time, there something i don't understand when defining the z coordinate of your ray. x,y is the location in NDC of your pixel but z sometime people said 0 sometimes -nearplane which should be -1 in general cases

Comment: @Rabbid76 It's ok to assume in NDC `ray.xy = NDCTextureCoord.xy;` and `ray.z = -nearPlane` in the plane intersection equation l0 should be a point belonguing to the ray, I assume the origin of the EyeSpace is a good choice so in eye space l0 = (0,0,0) I suppose it's ok

Comment: I find my error, i am usng a ortho projection matrix except that doing raycasting with thoose projection matrices don't work the same. You need to forward the point on your frustrum plane and then cast from this direction i will put the answer next week

Comment: You didn't put an answer after all, and I really would appreciate one, if it's still possible.

Comment: I don't have the code anymore, i had to compute the frustrum by hand and do some basic trigo to compute the rays. In the end it was not worth it, you still need to adjust the bias with a constant, it's leff than with a hard one